# How to construct a regex which accepts only 16 fields or less

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a text field. That field must accept at max 16 characters and nothing more than that.The format must be something like :

```
d1(13).d2(2) --> 98564785.52
```

So `d1` must contain at max 13 numbers(cannot be more than 13 but can be less than 13 , then need to give a dot(.) and there can be only one dot in the whole string . After the dot, it will accept only two numbers.

I tried with something like this `\d*{13}\.{1}\d{2}` . But it accepts all the dots . Kindly suggest some alternatives .

Comment: `\d*{13}\.\d{2}` no need of specify {1} for dot. try it.

Comment: @user1671639, you can't stack quantifiers like that.

Comment: Are you using the regex in a keypress event to prevent writing something that isin't valid or you are simply validating the final input value? There's a big difference between both.

Comment: Are two decimals mandatory? Is `.2` correct?

Comment: @smerny Can't get you.  Can you please explain?

Comment: @plalx : I am trying to  prevent writing something.

Comment: @M42 : Yes you are quite right .

Comment: @user1671639, `\d*{13}`, the `*` means "0 or more", then there is nothing between that quantifier and `{13}` so there is nothing to match 13 times.

Comment: @TheDarkKnight Well if you are trying to validate dynamic input, your selected solution will not work. You probably misunderstood my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try with:

```
^\d{1,13}\.\d{2}$
```

Comment: This works, I made a stupid mistake in the first capture group. I am hopeless ! Thanks. Accepted.

Answer (score 1):

Try this instead:

```
\d{1,13}\.\d{2}
```